# Oracle Trigger for incrementing Integer value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers, oracle10g, toad

I want to create Oracle trigger in Toad Modeler 5.3. This is the table:

[image]

In my case I need to add userID using trigger.

I'm stuck here:

[image]

[image]

Can you help me what should be the trigger body?

**EDIT**: Something like this?

```
create sequence t1_seq start with 1 increment by 1 nomaxvalue; 

BEGIN
    select t1_seq.nextval into :new.id_increment from dual;
END
```

Comment: You'd need to create a sequence (a separate object).  The trigger would then use the sequence.  An example of that is in the duplicate question.

Comment: @JustinCave Post updated. By the way where I have to specify which column is updated? Sorry but I don't have experience with SQL.